# Starting Express from Grunt ignores config JSON data

Tags: json, node.js, express, gruntjs

I have an express app which gets some config settings from seperate JSON files in a `./config` folder. For example, I'm setting the port for the server like this...

```
var config = require('config');

http.createServer(app).listen(config.port,function () {
    console.log('listening on '+config.port);   
});
```

This works fine if I cd into the express folder and run `npm start`.

However, when I start the Express `app.js` from Grunt using the [grunt-express-server](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server) task, it fails to read any of the information from the config files. (I've tested this by manually setting the port in the Express `app.js`: the express app now works, but throws up a new error saying it can't find the view folder.)

The folder structure of my project looks like this:

```
/project
  Gruntfile.js
  ...
  /express
    app.js
    config/
    views/
    ...
```

It seems the relative position of the `app.js` to the `config` and `views` folder is being ignored and the Grunt call wants to find things in the root (where it is).

Is there any way of stopping/remedying this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setup and directory structure.

When you use `require`, node [searches](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) for the required file in the directories listed in `NODE_PATH` env variable. The exception is when you use `'./'` in `require`, for example, `require('./config')`, in this case node will search your config in the directory where your file is located.

Probably, when you run your grunt task `NODE_PATH` is not properly set up to find your config file. So the solution may be is either:

1. Use `require('./config')` (better)
2. Or set `NODE_PATH` to the dir where your config file is located: `NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/path/to/dir grunt express`. You can also define `NODE_PATH` in your Grunt file (https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `require('./config')` is throwing up an error, whether started by Grunt or `npm start`. My Gruntfile is in the root, and the express app is in `express/app.js`. There are two node modules folders, one for Grunt (also in the root) and one for express (in the `/express/` folder).

Comment: Oh, and the config folder is at `/express/config/'

Comment: It's hard to guess where is the problem. Could you please add  your exact directory & files structure to the question? And the error messages? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Yaroslav. I think you're right about the folder structure being the problem but I'm still not sure how to solve it (other than placing everything in the same folder; not ideal). I've edited the question to show how things are laid out...

Comment: And what error is throwing when you do relative require('./config')? Also, content of your package.json and Gruntfile would be useful to debug your situation.